# Laravel : Extract ZipArchive file from storage external disk

Tags: php, laravel, zip, storage, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to extract a ZipArchive file located in an external storage disk in my laravel application. It is working on my local environment but not in production

My `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` env variable is different on production and working (tested with others Storage functions)

I have a zip file located in `Storage::path('folder/file.zip');` which I'm trying to extract in the same folder :

```php
// path to the zip file
$path = Storage::path('folder/file.zip');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($path) {
 $zip->extract(Storage::path('folder')); // working in local but not in production on an external disk
 $zip->close();
}
```

With this code, I receive a code **9** error : **No such file**
It says that my **$path** variable is wrong but if I debug `Storage::exists('folder/file.zip');` returns `true`

I don't know where I am missing something.

Comment: You are using a relative path, so the absolute path used is dependent on the working directory of the PHP process which is likely very different on production. If you want to access files relative to the PHP file you should prefix the path with the [\__DIR\__](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) constant.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think i get the theory but dont know how to write it down. The __DIR__ constant returns the controller my method is in :C/...../app/http/controllers/MyController, i'm not sure how i should proceed

Comment: Well, it depends on where your .zip is located. Lets say it is in `:C/...../app/uploads` and this is also true for your production version, you can get the correct path by doing: `$path = Storage::path(__DIR__ . '/../../../uploads/folder/file.zip');`. Not very nice due to the traverse up the directories but it works. You could also use environment variables or other means of configuration and specify the path to the directory that way.

Comment: I tried every path possible and it's still not working. my production __DIR__ try is like `home/{user}/application/app/storage/folder/file.zip`, the same as `storage_path().'/folder/file.zip'` and the same as `Storage::path('/folder/file.zip')`. All these tries are returning the same string. I'm not sure we are going in the good direction

Comment: Ah, I am starting to understand the situation better. I was not aware the the Storage class always adds the correct path prefix, this tripped me up. Is it at all possible that the PHP process/webserver has no read permissions on the zip file in production. In such a case you can still see that it exists but not read it.

Comment: Had a `Read Error` once, i'll try to get it again and work on it ! Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

The problem was you forgot to close the functional bracket of if condition:

```php
$path = Storage::path('folder/file.zip');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($path)) {
 $zip->extract(Storage::path('folder')); // working in local but not in production on an external disk
 $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).